# Can I select which file to archive in shutil?

Tags: python, zip, shutil

I want to archive only some files in my directory. Suppose that the following directory structure:

```
current_dir
  - current_file
    audio/
  - fileA
  - fileB
```

In this case, can I archive only `audio/` and `fileA` from the Python script (`current_file`)?

I use `shutil` but the following command seems to use all the files in a specific directory.

```
shutil.make_archive("new_file", 'zip', dir_name)
```

Comment: Consider using `zlib` instead of `shutil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible way to achieve what you want:

```
import os
import zipfile
import glob

content = [
    "audio",
    "fileA"
]


def zip_dir(path, zip_file):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            zip_file.write(os.path.join(root, file))

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile("mcve.zip", 'w')
for path in content:
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        zip_dir(path, zip_file)
    else:
        zip_file.write(path)
zip_file.close()
```